# Database import error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a database but I keep getting an error. Could anyone tell me what this means?

[image: database error]

Comment: You haven't selected a database upon entry to mysql

Comment: you can try to put at the beginning of the script `use nspire_wrdp2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a table, but have not said what database you want to create a table in. Try manually creating an empty database, and create the table in that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHPMyAdmin and have gone directly to the Import tab without first selecting a database from the column on the left, you will get this error.  You can tell if you haven't selected a database because the page heading will say "Importing into the Current Server" rather than "Importing into the database databasename".

In PHPMyAdmin, go to the database list in the column on the left, click on one to select, then click the import tab and upload your file.

Note: this clicking action performs the same function as the MySQL query `USE databasename`, which you could also just add to the SQL dump you are importing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database name nspire_wrdp2 then import.